# Cookie on page selection as home page for futrue visit

Tags: javascript, cookies

i m new in coding. currently having a project which allow user to select their preferred language page as their home page. To do this I'm using some code that posted by user her in stack overflow. but it seems not working properly, its stuck in loop loading. can someone point me to the problem is?

```js
var redirect = (function() {    

    var DEBUG = false,   // true to disable redirects
        NAME = 'redirect=', 
        DAYS = 7, // number of days to redirect
        cookie = document.cookie,
        expires;

    // read cookie and redirect 
    if (cookie.indexOf( NAME ) >= 0) {
        cookie = cookie.split( NAME ).pop().split(';').shift();
        cookie = decodeURIComponent( cookie );
        if (DEBUG) alert( 'Redirect\n' + cookie); else location.href = cookie;
    }

    // set redirect
    return function( url ) {
        if (confirm('Go to this link automatically on your next visit?')) {
            expires = new Date();
            expires.setDate( expires.getDate() + DAYS );
            cookie = 'redirect=' + encodeURIComponent( url ) + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString() + ';path=/';   
            document.cookie = cookie;
        }
        if (!DEBUG) location.href = url;
    }

})()
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://technical.walkerdendle.co.uk/_resx/images/logo.png">
    <br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="redirect('http://technical.walkerdendle.co.uk')">Technical</a>    
    <br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="redirect('http://financial.walkerdendle.co.uk')">Financial</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not give all anchor tags you want to use for redirecting a `class` name to bind a function and use the anchor tags inner text content to set the sub-domain? It could make your source code look cleaner and much easier to work with. If you have spaces in some of the text content you could always add `.replace()` and replace spaces with `-` or whatever you use to join the words.

Comment: hi this what i did  but it still the same. <span style="float:right;"><div class="language-toggle">
           <a href= "javascript:void(0)" onclick="redirect('http://toto4dresults.online/index.html')" ><span class="eng  language-selected">ENG</span></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="redirect('http://toto4dresults.online/index-ch.html')" ><span class="chinese">中文</span></a>
          </div> </span>